# Import Polymer Designer Output into Yeoman based Polymer app

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have created a core-scaffold based element in the Polymer Designer.
Using the Polymer Generator with Yeoman, I created a basic app and it displayed the page as expected. https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer/

I want to use the output from the designer in my app. I renamed designer.html (from gist) to dashboard.html, changed

```
<polymer-element name="my-element"> to
<polymer-element name="dashboard">
```

saved the designer output as: app/elements/dashboard/dashboard.html

changed all of the imports to the correct path, e.g.

```
<link rel="import" href="../core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html"> to
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html">
```

when I add

```
<link rel="import" href="dashboard/dashboard.html">
```

to elements.html and the page reloads, it is now blank.  This is without changing anything in index.html

Hints as to what else needs to be changed in the designer output for it to be imported to this app?

Comment: Adding the components to index.html does work.  But I still do not know why importing the designer output file into elements.html causes a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all Polymer elements MUST be hyphenated.

Comment: Tht i part of the Custom Elements spec, not Polymer. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#registering